# Installing Composer

Tags: php, composer-php, easyphp

I installed EasyPHP and then tried with Composer but it is complanning.
I can't finish the installation. First time happening to me, before everything was alright. How I can solve this?

> The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php5630vc11x86x180510141444\php.exe
>
> Program Output:
>   PHP Deprecated:  Comments starting with '#' are deprecated in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php5630vc11x86x180510141444\php.ini on line 886 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php5630vc11x86x180510141444\php.ini`, find line 886 and fix it.

Comment: I changed # for ;

Answer (score 0):

when you go to this directory C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\php\php5630vc11x86x180510141444\php.ini open the file php.ini and search in line 886 you find a #zend_extension = "" start with # change the # icone with ; and continu installing